# Was Jenkins CI named by Leeroy Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

[Jenkins(software)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_(software)) Wikipedia page says: 'As a result, on January 11, 2011, a call for votes was made to change the project name from "Hudson" to "Jenkins".'.

Reading into [Leeroy Jenkins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leeroy_Jenkins) wikipedia page, we can safely assume, that the  meme appeared in year 2005.

That means, whoever was making a suggestion for the new 'Hudson' name, could suggest 'Jenkins', based on popular meme. Can someone confirm/disprove?

Comment: I'm more inclined to think that it was named as a stereotypical butler's name, especially considering the icon for Jenkins.

Comment: `“Jenkins” — it’s another English-sounding butler name that doesn’t collide with any software project as far as I can tell.` from KK [here](http://kohsuke.org/2011/01/11/bye-bye-hudson-hello-jenkins/)

Comment: @KaiZhao You should really make that an answer, I'm not sure anyone is likely to get much closer than that to an official response.

Comment: @Tuffwer :) thank you but probably should not take credit for non-technical answers.

Comment: Beautiful question, too bad that it doesn't seem to be the case though :( Imagine deploying a rails app with capistrano using `cap leeeroy`- would be a fun one :P

Answer (score 7):

I assume inspiration for the name comes from the novel City by Clifford D. Simak The novel primarily focus around the Webster family and their robot servant, Jenkins.